# Insert current year into HTML

Tags: javascript

I am using javaScript that detects the current year, and then wish to inset this into the HTML. I have the following but it seems to be undefined.

Here is my code...

HTML

```
<p>this year is <span id="year"></span></p>
```

JavaScript

```
var date = document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = date;
```

I can do this in jQuery but I am trying to do this in vanailla javaScript, learning at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: n.b. This will be the year according to the system clock on the browsing machine, and not necessarily the year that the server believes it is

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure your element is read and ready to be manipulated:
Also fix your JS:

```html
<p>Year: <span id="year"></span></p>
        
<!-- JS right before the closing </body> tag -->
<script>
document.querySelector("#year").textContent = new Date().getFullYear();
</script>
```

Note that if one's computer clock is off, JavaScript might not be the right choice, in such case you can get the date from the backend.
If you use **PHP**:

```php
<p>Year <span id="year"><?php echo date("Y"); ?></span></p>
```

in short:

```php
<?= date("Y") ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Would it not be simpler and more efficient to simply do this in-line?

```
<p>this year is <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>.</p>
```

Comment: But probably not as readable and maintainable as Adam's version. I think of localization.

Comment: Exactly thomas_b, plus also the HTML is within a CMS HTML editor which doesn't allow javaScript.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var date = new Date().getFullYear();
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = date;
}
</script>
<p>this year is <span id="year"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = (new Date()).getFullYear();

document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `document.write` call. Try this:

```
var date = new Date().getFullYear();
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = date;
```

Answer (score -1):

This Javascript should work:

```
var date = (new Date().getFullYear()).toString();
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = date;
```

Answer (score -4):

to show date dynamically

```
<%=DateTime.Now.Year %>
<p>&copy;2016 School Apps. All Rights Reserved.</p>
```

To show 2016 dynamically  we use that code

Comment: Does this use a javascript solution, as asked in the original question? Looks like your answer may rely on ASP?